# Outlined react phone number input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've just started learning react, so this question can be east, but thank you for help. Now I'm using Material UI in my project, and I need outlined phone number input with flag and label, which looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZgSP.png)

But I can't find how to style any phone number picker to make it similar to this. Thnk you vey much for your help/

Comment: Could help ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number

Comment: as @Danial mentioned you can look for this package, otherwise you have to do little efforts to make your own component for phone numbers, you have to look for API for country telephone codes and then make UI for that data grabbed from API.

Comment: @Danial Thank you, that's the package I need, because its possible to use MUI TextField props here

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to grab InputBase from material-ui or just a regular html input tag and use className to style it. You could set the type="tel" or keep it as a string. You could add validation with yup to ensure that the right format is submitted.